# Convert css with 'not()' to less

Tags: css, less

I am trying to convert this code to to less, but on compile i got some errors

```
.navbar.nav-white *: not(li)>a {
    color: #62A2D8;
}
```

How to convert it to less?

Comment: http://beautifytools.com/css-to-less-converter.php

Comment: `.navbar.nav-white *:not(li)>a {` remove the whitespace between the semi-colon and not

Comment: @ZoltanToth You're right, that was the problem Thanks for the help!